# Execution error: [Vertica][VJDBC](4856) ERROR: Syntax error at or near "."

Tags: sql, vertica

Trying to insert this activity into my table but getting the error seen below. Any thoughts? SQL query checkers keep telling me its in my insert statement but I'm not seeing any outlier on my end. Thanks!

```
INSERT INTO
   "_CEL_MD_ACTIVITIES" ("_CEL_MD_ACTIVITIES"."CASE_KEY", "_CEL_MD_ACTIVITIES"."ACTIVITY_EN", "_CEL_MD_ACTIVITIES"."EVENTTIME") 
   SELECT
      "_CEL_MD_CASE_TABLE"."CASE_ID" AS "_CEL_MD_ACTIVITIES"."CASE_KEY",
      'Case Reopened' AS "_CEL_MD_ACTIVITIES"."ACTIVITY_EN",
      "_CEL_MD_CASE_TABLE"."CASE_REOPEN_DATE" AS "_CEL_MD_ACTIVITIES"."EVENTTIME" 
   FROM
      "_CEL_MD_CASE_TABLE" 
      JOIN
         "_CEL_MD_ACTIVITIES" 
         ON "_CEL_MD_CASE_TABLE"."CASE_ID" = "_CEL_MD_ACTIVITIES"."CASE_KEY" 
   WHERE
      "_CEL_MD_CASE_TABLE"."CASE_REOPEN_DATE" IS NOT NULL;
```

> Execution error: [Vertica]VJDBC ERROR: Syntax error at or near
> "."

Comment: Not sure which DB is in use, but I would think all the `"` should be `\``?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use as aliases the name and fields of a table involved in the join.
For example

```
AS   "_CEL_MD_ACTIVITIES"."ACTIVITY_EN",
```

This is not correct. You should change your alias names and not use dots (.) in them or remove the usage of aliases